# VB.NET - Conversion from string "11/07/2010 13:00:00" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, date

I am getting the error: Conversion from string "11/07/2010 13:00:00" to type 'Date' is not valid. In my ASP.NET code when run on the web server. The date is valid and it can't be a US format issue because either way it would be valid. I have tested it and it seems to error when the time is > 12:00 (ie. a 24hour like 13:00 or 21:00).

I've googled and only found a sugeestion to bounce IIS on the server.

Any ideas why ???

thanks
Dave

Comment: What code are you using to do the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s47fcc.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code is "IIf(startTime <> "", startTime & ":00", DateTime.MinValue)" and this is a parameter (datetime) into another method. startTime = "11/07/2010 13:00". I can wrap a date converter around it but I was just curious why it works for times <= 12:00 but not > 12:00 ?

Comment: BTW: THis works without any errors in development mode. It only fails when running the actual app on the test web server.